# Initial state for pristine input

Tags: javascript, validation, frontend

I have a very simple email input to which I am dynamically binding a CSS class on validation failure.

I am using a flag in state to track whether it is validated or not.

Obviously, by default, it is not validated. However it is rather obnoxious to style the input as a failure right off the bat.

I would like it to avoid displaying validation failure before any changes have been made.

Clearly this is more of a design question than an implementation one, however I have added my code below for reference (`Vue.js`).

How would you go about this?

```
<template>
  <p class="control has-addons">
    <input
      v-model="email"
      class="input is-large"
      :class="{'is-danger': !validated}"
      placeholder="Email">
    <a
      @click.prevent="submitEmail"
      class="button is-info is-large">
      Subscribe
    </a>
  </p>
</template>

<script>
import { isEmail } from 'validator'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      validated: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitEmail() {
      if (isEmail(event.target.value)) {
        this.validated = true
        this.$store.dispatch('submit_email', this.email)
      } else {
        this.validated = false
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue doesn't provide ["dirty" checking](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/96#issuecomment-35052704).

One option is to make your email variable an object with a property of "dirty".

```
email: {
        "value": null,
        "dirty": false,
        "validated": false,
        },
```

This way your code would be easy to track as you add more input fields.

Comment: I really like solution, still adding datakeys but more elegant

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of one more state key called something like `visited`. When the field gets blurred, set visited to true. Update your class condition to `visited && !validated`.

That would mean you don't start showing any error state until the user has focused and then moved away from the field without filling it in correctly.

Comment: Thanks for ans, was trying to avoid adding a key.

Comment: If you want to only add that class after the field has been visited, I don't see how you'll do that any cleaner than with a new state key. That's exactly the kind of thing state is for.